# I hear that Daedalus Is a Full Node Does That Mean I Can Set Up a DB Sync Server On Top of It?

Tags: daedalus, cardano-db-sync, api, blockfrost

The Daedalus wallet is said to be a full node wallet. Does that mean I can set up something similar to blockfrost on top of it? If so how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Daedaldus consists of two processes, `cardano-node` and the wallet itself.

Yes, it is possible to connect a `db-sync` instance to the `cardano-node`.

Comment: How do you do this? Is there a youtube video I could follow or some docs?

Comment: I do not know of a YT video or any docs.

However, all you need is to find the `cardano-node`'s socket file and then use the standard docs for `db-sync` to connect to that socket.